# Convert static java to companion object kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Friends I ask you a favor with this problem that I have when trying to implement a companion object for the following java code:

What is the correct way to do it?

```
private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
    }
```

Companion object

```
companion object Orientations {
        private var ORIENTATIONS: SparseIntArray? = null
        val orientations: SparseIntArray?
            get() {
                if (ORIENTATIONS == null) {
                    synchronized(SparseIntArray::class.java) {
                        if (ORIENTATIONS == null) {
                            ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray {
                                ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
                                ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
                                ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
                                ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ORIENTATIONS
            }
    }
```

generates the following error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:Int
Found:() → [ERROR : Cannot infer type variable TypeVariable(_L)]
```

Answer (score 1):

But in Java you don't have that `if (ORIENTATIONS == null) ...`. It should just be

```
companion object Orientations {
    // public because I assume it has a public getter in Java
    val ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray()

    init {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
    }
}
```

Or as Gurgen's answer shows how to simplify it:

```
companion object Orientations {
    val ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray().apply {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
    }
}
```

If you *do* want to make it lazy, Kotlin has [a solution in the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties) as Tenfour04's comment mentions, and it would look like

```
companion object Orientations {
    val ORIENTATIONS by lazy {
        SparseIntArray().apply {
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
            ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
        }
    }
}
```

but it's quite likely to be counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SparseIntArray().apply {
append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0)
append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90)
append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180)
append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270)
}
```

Comment: ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray {  ... } by
ORIENTATIONS = SparseIntArray.apply{ ... }. It works well,  ¿What does apply do?

Comment: Calls the specified function block with this value as its receiver and returns this value.

Comment: Also want to point out, if you want to lazy load it, use `by lazy` and you won't have to create the separate nullable property, double-checked lock, or synchronization as it will do it for you. But this is just a collection of a few Ints. There's not much point in making it lazy.